# Is it permissible to trespass without damaging someone’s property

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, bein-adam-lachavero, ownership, property

According to Halacha, is it permissible to go and trespass on someone else’s property if one doesn’t damage their property? For example, If one is on a trip to work and they can do a shortcut through someone’s backyard, is that permissible if they don’t otherwise affect the property?

Comment: I think there would be a problem of hezek re'iya

Comment: See Sukka 31a which implies that trespassing in someone's Sukka has no issue of mitzva habah be'aveirah, implying that there is no transgression involved. However some of the commentators pick up on the point ang give different interpretations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.81a.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he):

> וּמְהַלְּכִים בִּשְׁבִילֵי הָרְשׁוּת עַד שֶׁתֵּרֵד רְבִיעָה שְׁנִיָּה
>
> and they shall have the right to walk in permitted paths, i.e., those paths that cut through a private field, throughout the summer [actually, Rashi there says "after people have gathered in their harvest," which would be in the early autumn] until the second rainfall, when crops begin to sprout

- precisely because during that period there's no possible damage to the fields.

This is part of a list of enactments that Yehoshua made when the Jews first settled Eretz Yisrael (Bava Kamma 81a-b), although the Gemara ends up saying that this particular one was enacted later, by King Shlomo. They apply everywhere else in the world too ([ibid.](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.81b.9?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=he)), and are brought as halachah in [Tur, Choshen Mishpat 274:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Tur%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.274.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he).

Comment: Very nice! What about all cases of trespass?

Comment: What about a non-established path? (as is the standard modern urban case)

Comment: What if the owner doesn't let anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA We're not talking about established paths, otherwise those would be allowed all year round (Bava Basra 99b). And if the owner doesn't let, why then that's precisely what Shlomo's enactment is for - מהיות טוב אל תקרי רע, as the Gemara quotes.

Comment: It is talking about "paths" and most yards aren't paths at all. The enactment forces people to consent, but what if they violate the enactment and don't consent?

Comment: @DoubleAA A field isn't a "path" either. If they violate it, well then if there's no potential harm to them, כופין על מדת סדום. Where there are issues of privacy, etc., then that's something else.

Comment: If a field isn't a path then it's not included in שבילי הרשות and my question stands.

Comment: @DoubleAA Nope. Look at Rashi there: סתם בני אדם משהכניסו תבואתם עד שעת הזריעה מפקירים **שדותיהם** ליכנס בהן כל אדם לקצר את הדרך שלא יקיף **והן נקראין שבילי הרשות** לפי שברשות עושין והתנה יהושע שלא יקפידו על כך:

Comment: Still doesn't sound like most urban yards . though it does sound like the permission needs to be actively granted by the owner

Comment: @DoubleAA That it's not necessarily like a yard - granted; as Lo Ani noted in a comment, there may be issues of hezek re'iyah. That permission needs to be granted - no, the point is שלא יקפידו על כך. If the owner could get away with not granting such permission, then what would be the point of the takkanah? מה כח ב"ד יפה?

Comment: @Meir The point would be that the owner would be wrong and/or you don't (in a world where you can assume jews follow halacha) need to assume an owner would do that. (This is all still just the technical part of theft. If the owner really doesn't want it and would get angry, doing it anyway without some real need is still being a jerk.)

Comment: @DoubleAA And because the owner would be wrong, beis din could compel him to allow it. "If the owner really doesn't want it and would get angry" doesn't entitle him to act according to middas Sedom.

Comment: Perhaps beis din could compel him to allow it but nowadays they factually aren't. And whether or not he's entitled to doesn't answer what happens if he does anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Trespass is considered theft<sup>1,2</sup>

One cannot use someone's property, unless they have explicit permission. [Shulchan Aruch Choshen Mishpat 359:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.359.5?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%94%D7%97%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A3%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%91%22%D7%93%20%D7%94%22%D7%96%20%D7%92%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%A2%22%D7%A4%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%95%D7%90%20%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%91%20%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%A6%22%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%9D%20%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%20%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%97%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%95%3A%20%D7%90%D7%99%D7%96%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%92%D7%96%D7%9C%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%97%20%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%94%20%D7%9B%D7%92%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%98%D7%A3%20%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%A1%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%9C%D7%A8%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%9C%20%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9D%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A3%20%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%93%D7%95%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%AA%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%A9%20%D7%91%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%20%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%9A%20%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%90%20%D7%91%D7%96%D7%94%3A&with=Bava%20Metzia&lang2=en)

> הלוקח בשאלה שלא מדעת הבעלים נקרא גזלן:
>
> Someone who borrows [the property of someone else] without the owner
> knowing, is called a thief

It doesn't matter about the lack of change in value. See [Bava Metzia 43b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.43b.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

---

<sup>1 - [Tosfot Bava Kama 20b ד"ה הא איתהנית](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.20b.1?lang=he&with=Tosafot&lang2=he); [Rema SA CM 363:6, Biur HaGra](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.363.6?lang=en&with=Beur%20HaGra&lang2=en); [Rashbam on Bava Batra 57b ד"ה לקולא](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashbam_on_Bava_Batra.57b.4.4?lang=he&with=all&lang2=en)

2 - As Meir pointed out, there is an exception. See [Meir's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140213/31534), and comments there, and note the halachot of nezek riya.</sup>

Comment: Nope. That applies to movable property (where you're depriving the other person of its use while you borrow it), not land. See my answer.

Comment: @Meir I think you've found a very specific exception to the rule (which does deal with the *example* given in the question), rather than dealt with the point of trespass in its entirety.

Comment: Ze nehene ze lo chasser is only after the fact. You can't park in someone's drive, or sit in someone's seat, or stow away on a bus, even if there is no loss to the owners

Comment: Very well, you're right that it's not limited to movables as I said. But the cases in the sources you've brought are referring to occupancy, where you're thereby preventing the owner from using it, not to taking a shortcut across his property, which does not.

Comment: @Meir ok thanks. Even if that is the case (we'd need to discuss), the question we are answering isn't limited to lack of occupancy but lack of damage. That's the only limit.